# Elastic beanstalk app not connected to the nginix

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Facing this error in logs after successfully deployment

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------
2020/10/23 07:41:02 [error] 4697#0: *412 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.33.154, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.17.64"
```

Here is my package.json script

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec 'node ./bin/www'",
    "abc": "nodemon ../script.js"
  },
```

Bin file look like this

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "8080");

This logs show me server is running successfully successfully

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Oct 23 08:39:50 ip-172-31-17-64 web: init cron
Oct 23 08:39:51 ip-172-31-17-64 web: web server listening on port 8081
Oct 23 08:39:51 ip-172-31-17-64 web: you are connected to database
```

Comment: If you ssh into the EB instance, can you confirm that it works as expected, by `curl`ing your application on localhsot?

Comment: i am not using ssh. using eb cli to deploy

Comment: So how do you know that your app is working as expected? Maybe it crashed, thus nginx can't connect to it?

Comment: Its locally working fine when i deploy by using eb cli it show me message of  Instance deployment completed successfully.

Comment: Maybe nginx can't connect to it, how can i fix this ?

Comment: ```/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Oct 23 06:44:20 ip-172-31-17-64 web: Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Oct 23 07:15:25 ip-172-31-17-64 web: init cron
Oct 23 07:52:00 ip-172-31-17-64 web: init cron
Oct 23 08:07:22 ip-172-31-17-64 web: /bin/sh: gunicorn: command not found
Oct 23 08:07:22 ip-172-31-17-64 web: /bin/sh: gunicorn: command not found
Oct 23 08:07:22 ip-172-31-17-64 web: /bin/sh: gunicorn: command not found
Oct 23 08:09:11 ip-172-31-17-64 web: init cron```